# FileInfo: passing FileInfo argument to method

Tags: vb.net, fileinfo

I have the following VB function which takes a FileInfo object as a parameter:

```
Public Shared Shadows Sub Start(ByVal filePath As FieldInfo)
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(New System.IO.FileInfo(filePath.ToString()))

End Sub
```

In another class I have the following code calling that 'Start' method.  But VisStudio indicates there is a problem with the 'FilePath' argument that I'm passing.  Thanks in advance!

```
'Initialize FileInfo object to pass to Start method
        Dim path As String =             Dim filePath As FileInfo = New FileInfo(path)

        LoggingManager.Start(**FilePath**)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you mis-declared the Start function, it should be FileInfo not FieldInfo

```
Public Shared Shadows Sub Start(ByVal filePath As FileInfo)
    XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(filePath)
End Sub
```